# Custom title for map annotation

Tags: ios, mapkit

In my map app, the user can enter an address in a search bar, and the location is displayed with a red pin. Is it possible within my code to let the user enter a custom title and subtitle before the pin is placed on the map? The title and subtitle should show up in the callout bubble. How is this done? Right now, all my pin titles are "My Place."

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar

{

    if (!self.geocoder)
    {
        self.geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    }

    NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.searchBar.text];

    [self.geocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if ([placemarks count] > 0)
        {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;

            NSLog (@"%f %f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);

            MKCoordinateRegion region;
            MKCoordinateSpan span;
            span.latitudeDelta = 0.01;
            span.longitudeDelta = 0.01;
            region.span = span;
            region.center = coordinate;

            MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
            [annotation setCoordinate:coordinate];
            [annotation setTitle:@"My Place"];
            [[self mapView] addAnnotation:annotation];

            [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
            [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];

            [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
            self.searchBar.text = @"";

        }
    }];

}
```

Also, how can all of my pins be saved to NSUserDefault, so that they show up when the app is restarted? Would this work, or will this only save one pin?

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [defaults setDouble:coordinate.latitude forKey:allPins_latitude];
                [defaults setDouble:coordinate.longitude forKey:allPins_longitude];
                [defaults setBool:YES forKey:allPins_coordinates];
                [defaults synchronize];
```

I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set a different title and subtitle for each point you'll need to provide a text box for the user to enter the data. Once done it's as simple as the code you already have

```
NSString *title = [self.titleField stringValue];
[annotation setTitle:@"title"];
NSString *subtitle = [self.subtitleField stringValue];
[annotation setSubtitle:@"title"];
```

However you may not have the screen space to show three textfields. What [I do](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tiled-maps/id472255447?mt=8) is create the pin with a default name, then allow the user to open the callout bubble, or open it automatically and show a button to edit it, then show a modal dialog over the top to edit the title and subtitle

If you saved every `coordinate.latitude` under the key `allPins_latitude` then each one would overwrite the previous and you'd only have the last one saved. If your pins are all stored as an array, store the array.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. I do have one question though... I am just staring out learning how to use map kit. My callout views already have a button, but how can I show a modal dialog with this button? And how can I store my pins as an array?

Comment: Btw, I clicked on the link you provided. Your app looks good.

Comment: Both of those questions should be a new entry on Stackoverflow, it helps others with the same problem find solutions, but the thing you're looking for with the callout is `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` When the button is tapped it'll go to that function and you can do whatever you want, including showing modal dialog.

The array stuff is easy. Everything a new pin is added, add it to an array. Give it a go and then ask a new question when you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can have your user enter a title.

Your code above creates an annotation object and sets it's title to a fixed title.

### Edit:

Note that this answer is from 2013. UIAlertView has since been deprecated. In recent versions of iOS you should instead use a `UIAlertController`. If I have time I'll provide more recent guidance on the specifics of using a `UIAlertController`, but it's well documented and there should be plenty of examples out there to look at.

---

Instead of doing that, create your annotation, save it to an instance variable, and display an alert view using the UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput to collect a name for the annotation. Make yourself the delegate of the alert view, and then in your alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: method, if the user clicks ok, get title from the alert view, set the title property on the annotation, and add the annotation to the map

As for saving your annotations to user defaults:

I would suggest creating your own object that conforms to the MKAnnotation object. It just needs to have a coordinate property, a title property, and a subtitle property. Make your annotation object conform to the NSCoding protocol (implement initWithCoder and encodeWithCoder.)

Once you do that, you can convert your entire array of annotation objects to NSData using the NSKeyedArchiver class method archivedDataWithRootObject. Then just save the data to user defaults. On launch, read the NSData object, convert it back to an array of your custom annotation objets using unarchiveObjectWithData:, and add the annotations back to your map.

Comment: Thanks, I really like your UIAlertView solution. I will try and do this. As for the MKAnnotation object, I am not sure how to do this. Would you be willing to share some sample code, or tell me where I can find a tutorial? I would greatly appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

@petter I think below code will help you
 //swift 3

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

       let Userlocation : CLLocation = locations[0]

       let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Userlocation.coordinate.latitude
           , longitude: Userlocation.coordinate.longitude)


        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation() 
        annotation.coordinate = center 
        annotation.title = "title" 
        Annotation.subtitle = “Subtitle”
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span:  MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

      mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

   }
```